# Telerik RadGridView disabled a specific cell for a specific row

Tags: c#, winforms, telerik, telerik-grid

In telerik Rad GridView (2014) Winform, i have a gridview with a disabled column but if i type an especific text in another column i want that column to be enabled to write, but only the cell for that specific row

Answer (score 0):

Since you want to some cells editable, you should not disable the whole column. For the purpose of your case, you can use the CellBeginEdit event, which you can cancel if your condition is not met, hence the user will not be able to edit the specified cell:

```
    void radGridView1_CellBeginEdit(object sender, GridViewCellCancelEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Column.Name == "columnAtHand" && e.Row.Cells["DependantColumn"].Value == "disallowEdit")
        {
            e.Cancel = true;
        }
    }
```